# MySQL- Getting a SUM when a variable inside it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, view, sum, inner-join

first post here!

So as a young Padawan in SQL and Databases in general  I am working on creating a database for a business to manage orders/items/prices etc. I want to create a View that from 3 linked tables {items,prices,discounts}(see tables at the bottom) calculates and show the total price of an item. As a rule, the discount column shouldn't be zero( because we only want in the table `discounts` entries with actual discount , not 0 )

From the following entries I want to show **all** of them but my view **only** shows the one's with discounts.

```
insert into items (`item_id`,`item_name`, `item_quantity`) values
(102,'item1',20),
(103,'item2',20),
(404,'item3',20); # <-- It won't be shown if I do SELECT * FROM view;

insert into discounts (`item_id`,`discount`) values
(102,50),
(103,25);

insert into prices (`item_id`,`price`) values
(102,100),
(103,100),
(404,100);
```

And here is my View:

```
CREATE VIEW ItemsPrice AS
SELECT 
    i.item_id,
    i.item_name,
    SUM((1-d.discount/100)*p.price*i.item_quantity)   

FROM
    items AS i
    INNER JOIN 
        prices AS p ON i.item_id=p.item_id
    INNER JOIN
        discounts AS d ON (p.item_id=d.item_id)    
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY total;
```

Here are my tables (just in case I made them wrong):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `items`;
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `item_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
    `item_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    `item_quantity` double(25,0) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)

);
#2=======
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prices`;
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
    `item_id`int(30) NOT NULL,
    `price` decimal(30,2) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `prices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`item_id`)   
);
#3=======
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `discounts`;
CREATE TABLE `discounts` (
    `item_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
    `discount` int(3) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `discount_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items` (`item_id`)
);
```

## Sorry for not providing a schema. Don't know how to make one.

Hope I didn't waste much of your time! You are my hero.

Comment: Nicely worded question, clear and to the point, with all necessary supporting details. You will go far in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a left join - this will grab all items with prices even of they do not have a discount.  You use COALESCE to replace the NULL discounts with a valid number.

```
SELECT 
    i.item_id,
    i.item_name,
    COALESCE(d.discount,0) as discount,
    p.price,
    i.item_quantity
FROM
    items AS i
    INNER JOIN 
        prices AS p ON i.item_id=p.item_id
    LEFT JOIN
        discounts AS d ON (p.item_id=d.item_id)    
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY total;
```

Your query with COALESCE:

```
SELECT 
    i.item_id,
    i.item_name,
    (1-COALESCE(d.discount,0)/100)*p.price*i.item_quantity) as totalAmount  
FROM
    items AS i
    INNER JOIN 
        prices AS p ON i.item_id=p.item_id
    LEFT JOIN
        discounts AS d ON (p.item_id=d.item_id)    
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY total;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast reply.
Now it indeed shows the entry '404' but with a total value of NULL,

Comment: Hang on, I see you edited to add the select.  I can fix that.

Comment: While I think on that - why the SUM?  Do you have multiple items with the same item_ID?

Comment: It works! I don't 'need' SUM , I just don't know what else to use.( no dublicate )

Comment: Did the COALESCE with a 0 actually run?  I thought that would throw a divide by zero error.